# Exclude images from CSS filter

Tags: css, colors

I got this css class (its applied on the body)
and i don't wan't to invert the color of the images.
how can i prevent this?

```
.dark{
  filter: invert(1);
  background-color: #222;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML code?

Comment: I would try to fix the method which is the big issue here rather that trying to create more issue. Don't use filter to create a dark mode, use proper methods

Comment: but it looks pretty awesome for the dark mode just the pictures are horrible

Comment: why you need html code?

Comment: *but it looks pretty awesome for the dark mode* --> because you still didn't discover all the issues. You have only one now and more will come soon. Changing the method now will avoid you a lot of hassle later

Comment: @TemaniAfif I will check it out. but thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try using `:not` selector.

Edit: Using `:not` won't work here

Comment: you mean .dark:not(img) ?

Comment: Or you can use
`:not(img) {  
  filter: invert(1);  
  background-color: #222;  
}`
instead of using `dark` in body

Comment: kinda nice but i have to toggle it with javascript.

Comment: In that case, you can add `.dark img { filter: invert(1);  }`   after `.dark{
  filter: invert(1);
  background-color: #222;
}`